# Neural Nets for Image + numeric Data

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have a situation where input is an image and a group of (3) numeric fields and output is an image mask. I am not sure about how to do that in KERAS...

My architecture is somewhat like the attachment. I am aware about the CNN and Dense architectures, just not sure how to pass the inputs in the corresponding networks and do the concat operation. Also, suggestion of berrer architecture for this will be great!!!!!

Please suggest me, preferably with example code. 
Thanks in Advance, Utpal.[image]

Comment: After applying a fully connected layer to the input in the lower branch any spatial information is lost (since a distance between points makes no difference to dense layers). Hence applying then conv/deconv (which is sensitive to a spatial structure of the input) doesn't make much sense, up to me. Can you describe a problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Asume that you are given human faces along with age and gender, you need to locate if the face have any Birth Mark (not just any type of mark).... Output will be a 2D image where Birth Marks are pointed with white (1 or 255) and the rest of the image will be black (0) ...

Comment: if it's enough to create only yes/no (0/255) image mask, then it's an image segmentation problem. You can try keras implementation of some models from following repo as a starting point - https://github.com/divamgupta/image-segmentation-keras

Comment: Thanks for this, but here, the numeric data is important, just the CNN (VGG) might not do enough....

Comment: Just wondering where to fit the numeric data (apart from the image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can advice to try U-net model for this problem. Usual U-net represents several conv and maxpooling layers, and then several conv and upsampling layers:

[image]

In the current problem you can mix up non-spatial data (image annotation) at the middle:

[image]

Also maybe it's a good idea to start with pre-trained VGG-16 (see below `vgg.load_weights(VGG_Weights_path)`).

See code below (based on [Divam Gupta's repo](https://github.com/divamgupta/image-segmentation-keras/blob/master/Models/VGGUnet.py)):

```
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *


def VGGUnet(n_classes, input_height=416, input_width=608, data_length=128, vgg_level=3):
    assert input_height % 32 == 0
    assert input_width % 32 == 0

    # https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.1/vgg16_weights_th_dim_ordering_th_kernels.h5
    img_input = Input(shape=(3, input_height, input_width))
    data_input = Input(shape=(data_length,))

    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(img_input)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv2', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    f1 = x
    # Block 2
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv2', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    f2 = x

    # Block 3
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv2', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv3', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    f3 = x

    # Block 4
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv2', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv3', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    f4 = x

    # Block 5
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv2', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv3', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    f5 = x

    x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
    x = Dense(1000, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

    vgg = Model(img_input, x)
    vgg.load_weights(VGG_Weights_path)

    levels = [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5]

    # Several dense layers for image annotation processing
    data_layer = Dense(1024, activation='relu', name='data1')(data_input)
    data_layer = Dense(input_height * input_width / 256, activation='relu', name='data2')(data_layer)
    data_layer = Reshape((1, input_height / 16, input_width / 16))(data_layer)

    # Mix image annotations here
    o = (concatenate([f4, data_layer], axis=1))

    o = (ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)
    o = (Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='valid', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)
    o = (BatchNormalization())(o)

    o = (UpSampling2D((2, 2), data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)
    o = (concatenate([o, f3], axis=1))
    o = (ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)
    o = (Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='valid', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)
    o = (BatchNormalization())(o)

    o = (UpSampling2D((2, 2), data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)
    o = (concatenate([o, f2], axis=1))
    o = (ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)
    o = (Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='valid', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)
    o = (BatchNormalization())(o)

    o = (UpSampling2D((2, 2), data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)
    o = (concatenate([o, f1], axis=1))
    o = (ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)
    o = (Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='valid', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)
    o = (BatchNormalization())(o)

    o = Conv2D(n_classes, (3, 3), padding='same', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(o)
    o_shape = Model(img_input, o).output_shape
    output_height = o_shape[2]
    output_width = o_shape[3]

    o = (Reshape((n_classes, output_height * output_width)))(o)
    o = (Permute((2, 1)))(o)
    o = (Activation('softmax'))(o)
    model = Model([img_input, data_input], o)
    model.outputWidth = output_width
    model.outputHeight = output_height

    return model
```

To train and evaluate a keras model with several inputs prepare separate arrays for each of the input layers - `image_train` and `annotation_train` (preserving an order by the first axis, i.e. number of the sample) and call this:

```
model.fit([image_train, annotation_train], result_segmentation_train, batch_size=..., epochs=...)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate([image_test, annotation_test], result_segmentation_test)
```

Good luck!